# Gnuplot boxes with one different color bar

Tags: gnuplot, bar-chart

I am making a plot and I need to show the last bar of another color. How can I do it??

This is my code:

```
set output 'mediaedad.png'
set title 'Media de edad de los equipos'
set term png
set ylabel 'Edades'
set yrange [0:40]
set xlabel 'Equipo'
set xtics rotate
set style fill solid border
set boxwidth 0.5
set datafile separator comma
set grid nopolar
plot 'mediaequipos.txt' using 2:xtic(1) notitle with boxes
```

And my plot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP didn't specify the color, so I assume any color would be fine if it satisfy the requirement "the last bar of another color".
Data was also unavailable, therefore I generated a small set stored in the file:
"gnuptest_bars.txt".

```
a,1
b,2
c,2.2
d,3
```

A possible solution, based also on this answer ( [Gnuplot color every nth box in histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201727/gnuplot-color-every-nth-box-in-histogram?rq=1)) is the following:

```
set title 'Media de edad de los equipos'

set ylabel 'Edades'
set yrange [0:5]
set xlabel 'Equipo'
set xtics rotate
set style fill solid border
set boxwidth 0.5
set datafile separator comma
set grid nopolar
plot 'gnuptest_bars.txt' using 2:xtic(1) notitle with boxes

N=system("cat gnuptest_bars.txt | wc -l")
plot "gnuptest_bars.txt" u 0:2:((int($0)+1)%N==0?(255<<16):255):xticlabels(1) with boxes lc rgbcolor variable notitle
```

[image]

Comment: A suggestion: the line `N=system("cat... )` will work for Linux but not for Windows. So, I would suggest instead: `stats "gnuptest_bars.txt" u 0 nooutput; N=STATS_records`.  Check `help stats` and `show var STATS`. This would be _gnuplot-only_ and hence _platform-independent_.